# Can you lock objects in Illustrator so it doesn't keep being selected and highlighted?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I was trying to draw behind many shapes but I couldn't tell where I was drawing because of many lines highlighting. But I need those shapes to draw correctly just not their stroke lines highlighting. Usually a problem when adjusting curved or making anchor point using pen tool.

How do I lock objects in Illustrator to keep this from happening?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, in the layers panel, there is a little checkbox next to every object and layer.

Answer (score 7):

Layers Panel icons as KMSTR points out.

But there's also....
Object > Lock > Selection (<kbd>Command/CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd>)
Object > Lock > All Artwork Above
Object > Lock > Other Layers

And there's a hidden shortcut <kbd>Command/CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Option/Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> to "lock others". This command will lock anything **NOT selected**.

Comment: Aweesommee!!!!!!

Comment: DUDE! You are an Illustrator GOD.

Comment: :) @LaurenIpsum works with 3 to "Hide Others" as well :)